# Código fonte diferente para versão release/debug

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Vi que no android studio é possível ter um AndroidManifest.xml para a versão debug e outro para versão release. Pois bem, tenho um arquivo "AppMock.java" com constantes para teste.

Gostaria não compilar esse código fonte na versão release ou criar uma classe vazia para ser compilada.

Tem alguma forma de isolar ou diferenciar este código na hora da geração da versão release?

Comment: Isso é possível. mas ao utilizar as variantes debug e release se, por exemplo, a MainActivity chamar métodos dessa classe ela tem de existir nas duas variantes, no entanto os métodos podem ter implementações diferentes. Se isso for impeditivo terá de usar *Flavors*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Android Studio, quando cria um modulo, automaticamente cria os [build types](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#build-types) ***debug*** e ***release***.
No entanto, apenas cria o [source set](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#sourcesets)
 `main/`.

Para que possa colocar código para ser usado como *Build Variants*(diferentes versões da app) desses *build types*, tem de criar os respectivos *source set*.

Para criar os *source set*, siga os seguintes passos:

- No painel **Project** escolha a vista *Project*(1).
- Clique com o botão direito sobre a pasta `/app/src` e escolha a opção **New->Folder->Java Folder**(3).
  Na janela que aparece, escolha *debug* para **Target source set**.
  Clique em <kbd>Finish</kbd>.
- Repita o passo anterior, encolhendo *release* para **Target source set**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pasta `/app/src` terá agora, além da pasta `/main`, as pastas `debug/` e `release/`

Na pasta `/main` é colocado o código comum às duas variantes, nas pastas `debug/` e `release/`, o que é especifico a cada uma.

Mas antes, deverá criar uma *Package* em cada uma das pastas `/debug/java` e `/release/java`:

- No painel **Build Variants**(2) assegure-se que está seleccionada a variante *debug*(4).
- Clique com o botão direito na pasta `/debug/java` e escolha a opção **New->Package** e introduza o nome da *package*.
- No painel **Build Variants**(2) seleccione a variante *release*.
- Clique com o botão direito na pasta `/release/java` e escolha a opção **New->Package** e introduza o nome da *package*.

A estrutura de pasta ficará idêntica à da figura seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Antes de executar, escolha no painel **Build Variants**, a variante a construir.

Para mais informação veja [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) na documentação.