# Como alternar visualização de diretórios de debug para release, ou vice-versa?

Tags: android-studio

No Android Studio no canto lateral esquerdo é possível definir o tipo de visualização de em relação a estrutura de diretórios, como no meu caso mostra está definido Android. Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, está sublinhado o `google_maps_api.xml(debug)` dentro do diretório `values`. Existe uma forma de em vez de mostrar arquivos de `debug`, mostrar os de `release`? Como alternar visualização de diretórios de `debug` para `release`, ou vice-versa?

Comment: Relacionado: [Código fonte diferente para versão release/debug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155343/2541).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siga os seguintes passos:

- 1) No canto inferior esquerdo da IDE clique na aba Build Variants.
- 2) Na janela que abre, na coluna Build Variant, escolha `release`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Era exatamente isso! Obrigado.