# Google Maps não funciona depois que gero APK Assinado para a Google Play

Tags: android, google, maps

Pessoal tenho uma aplicação rodando Google Maps. Gerei a chave de acesso (copiei e colei no xml ) direto no site Console Developer. Se eu gerar o apk normal (sem assinatura) ele funciona normalmente. Depois que gero o apk assinado (para postar no Google Play) ele não carrega mais o mapa, aparece o logo da google porém o mapa não é carregado.

Li que precisa usar a mesma key que gerei no site no apk assinado. Só não entendi como gerar a chave, já que a chave que peguei no site foi (copiada e colada). Estou tentando assinar direto na IDE Android Studio, no menu Build > Generate Signed APK

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isso?

Comment: Gerou chave como release?

Comment: @acklay sim gerei com release

Comment: @acklay se eu gerar como debug, o apk funciona . Porém se eu subir na Google Play ele fala que a chave SHA esta diferente e não deixa subir para substituir o apk já existente na gplay

Comment: Tem que gerar sha1 como release mesmo. Eu já apanhei  muito com isso, mas hoje sei que quando acontece isso é exatamente por causa do token errado. Tenta conferir exatamente se está enviando como release. Verifique se não tem dois arquivos google_maps_api.xml(debug) e google_maps_api.xml(release).

Comment: @acklay notei isso mesmo. No meu só tenho o google_maps_api.xml(debug). Como faço para ter o gogole_maps_api.xml(release)? É o mesmo arquivo , só renomear?

Comment: Não é o mesmo arquivo. Você tem que entrar na pasta do seu projeto. em app/src e verá os modos. release/debug/test etc. Ai entra em release e coloca sua chave de release. Só isso e tudo funcionará perfeitamente.

Comment: Olha essa minha pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216685/como-alternar-visualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-diret%C3%B3rios-de-debug-para-release-ou-vice-versa

Comment: @acklay muito obrigado pela ajuda. Deu certinho, segui o que você me mandou no link, e depois apareceu o xml release da google. Coloquei minha Api key. Gerei o arquivo como release e funcionou. Testei na google play e já reconheceu também como atualização do antigo apk. Valeu =D

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216700/130213 "Esta Resposta resolveu meu problema"

Comment: E vc usou a chave do google play em vez da chave do Android Studio pra gerar o SHA1?
No meu caso em debug funciona, mas quando copio o apk para o aparelho e instalo, não funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já apanhei bastante com essa questão de enviar APK e não funcionar depois de lançado. O que deves observar é que existe o modo **DEBUG** e **RELESE** no *app* quando é criado o projeto no Android Studio e também quando é gerada uma chave no [console do Google](https://console.developers.google.com), para quais quer que seja a API que será usado.

O que pode estar acontecendo é que deves estar alterando somente a API do modo DEBUG e não está alterando o modo RELEASE em sua aplicação. Veja essa pergunta que fiz sobre: [Como alternar visualização de diretórios de debug para release, ou vice-versa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216685/como-alternar-visualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-diret%C3%B3rios-de-debug-para-release-ou-vice-versa)

Verifique se há dois arquivos `google_maps_api.xml(debug)` e `google_maps_api.xml(release)` no diretório `app/src`  e faça a correção devida.

Answer (score 0):

Após ler a minha chave.keystore

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Eu limitei o acesso as apis somente a minha chave de lançamento.

Após quebrar muito a cabeça descobri que há uma assinatura no portal do Google play. **Gerencimanto da versão => Assinatura de Apps**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que tenho duas restrições adicionadas, isso aconteceu comigo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]