# Google Maps não funciona (Após publicar na google play)

Tags: google-maps, google-play

Quando gero o apk assinado na Google Play, o Google maps não funciona, já coloquei a chave no google_maps_api tanto de debug como do release como diz nesse tutorial:
[Google Maps não funciona depois que gero APK Assinado para a Google Play](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219072/google-maps-n%C3%A3o-funciona-depois-que-gero-apk-assinado-para-a-google-play) mais ainda não funcionou, alguém sabe o motivo disso?

Tenho minha chave normalmente:

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">minha chave</string>
```

O mesmo está tando no debug como no release...

Comment: Olá @samuel, pode pf colocar o código que já tem? Será mais fácil ajudarmos. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para melhor perceber o funcionamento do _site_.

Comment: <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
          Minha chave
    </string>

Comment: Edita a sua questão e coloque lá o seu código.

Comment: @JoãoMartins alguma ideia do que seja, veja esse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219072/google-maps-n%C3%A3o-funciona-depois-que-gero-apk-assinado-para-a-google-play, fiz igual mais não resolveu...

Comment: Resolvido, o SHA1 que estava no googleApis não era o mesmo da minha chave de assinatura, usei o comando no terminal na pasta bin do java: keytool -list -v -keystore nomedasuachave e coloquei o Sha1 correto.